# Android Volley empty error

Tags: android, android-volley

I don't understand how this code gives an empty error. This code seems alright to me.

Volley

```
String url = "https://xxx";
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            /* some code */
        }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

When I execute this, it shows an empty error coming from `onErrorResponse` function. Strangely, some of the class that using this Volley works just fine. I have tried to fix this everywhere, but to no avail. I tested this on Android API 26 (virtual).

Comment: Have you tried using postman to determine that your url endpoint is working properly?

Comment: Can Postman work in Android?

Comment: No, I mean to check whether it's the API stuff which is not working, not your code in Android. Since, the code seems to be no problem.

Comment: API seems fine. The result is shown using Postman.

Comment: It's fine now. My code works. It's just a timeout problem. I have fixed that.